# Updating the total cost of candies by increasing or decreasing count in Input Box - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding

In a simple program, I want to increase or decrease the number of candies and then print its cost (* 5, as cost of 1 candy is $5) adjescant to input box. Unforutnately value is not updating. Can someone help out?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    candy: 0,
    candyPrice: 0
  }
  render() {

    return (
    <div>
        <input type="number" value={this.state.candy} onChange={this.alpha} name="candy" id="candy"/>
        <span>{this.state.candyPrice}</span>
    </div>
   )
   alpha = (ev) => {
    this.setState({
            [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value
    });
    this.state.candyPrice = this.state.candy * 5; 
   }
   
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You need `this.state` in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a few things in your code:

- Move your `onChange` event handler outside the render method.
- Use `this.setState` instead of directly mutating your state object when updating the `candyPrice`.
- **Why not mutate the state directly?** When you mutated the state using this `this.state.candyPrice`, it caused an odd bug where the displayed candy price is the value of the previous input * 5.

> Directly modifying state is not recommended as `React` will not know
>   the change and it will not cause a re-render.

---

With that in mind, your event handler should look similar to this.

```js
alpha = ev => {
  const candies = ev.target.value;
  this.setState({
    [ev.target.name]: candies,
    candyPrice: candies * 5
  });
};
```

See [working implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/m4jrv699ny).